# How to use the font catalog to see how accented characters show

Tags: fonts

I would like to select a font which looks good for french text with accented characters. The font catalog shows for each font the same `the quick brown fox ...` example, which is not helpful for me, because it does not include any accented characters.

Is there a way to use the font catalog to give examples with a different text of my choosing (e.g. one with accented characters).

Comment: Pick a few that look OK, cook up your own "Quick brown fox" text with many all sorts of accented letters, and compare... Consider contributing your text to the catalogue.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to do it? The text could be "La r\^{e}ve de Ren\'{e}e".